# Google+ & YouTube Integration

Tags: ios, xcode, youtube-api, google-plus

I have an iOS app which includes sharing links to Google+ and uploading videos on YouTube. First I completed with sharing links on Google+ (Followed Post: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)

For uploading videos on YouTube, I followed tutorial (Link: https://nsrover.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/youtube-api-on-ios/)

The problem is that Header Files clash giving error “Redefinition of enumerator” in Xcode 5.1.1.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: check enum defined twice in ur project

Comment: Can you post the specific lines of code where you see this error?

Comment: @Vishnu: the enums are defined twice due to Google+ framework and Gdata client for iOS.

Comment: @JAL: enum {
  kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorDownloadFailed = -1,
  kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorAuthenticationChallengeFailed = -2,
  kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorChunkUploadFailed = -3,
  kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorFileHandleException = -4,
  kGTMHTTPFetcherErrorBackgroundExpiration = -6,

Here are the lines, due to which conflict occurs. There are some more, but here are some lines.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following up rather late here:

Google has restructured their entire SDK.  Upgrading my copy of the Google Sign-In SDK to version 2.4.0 fixed the enum issues for me.

Google recommends using Cocoapods to manage their SDK dependency now, so remove the old SDK from your project and add the new SDK via Cocoapods: `pod install Google`.

If you are not using Cocoapods, you can manually install the Sign-In SDK by downloading it from [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/) and linking the binary with your project.